# Where can I store loaded textures used for visualizing a certain object?

Tags: c++, oop, getter, single-responsibility-principle

I have a drawable class `Button`. Should its textures be stored and hidden inside:

```
class Button {
 private:
  Texture idle, hovered, clicked;
 public:
  void draw_self(Window&, Position) const;
};
void App::draw() {
  button.draw_self(window, position);
}
```

...or is it more sensible to remember some kind of proxy and provide a soulless getter for being used by "cleverer" abstractions?

```
class Button {
 private:
  std::string idle_tag, hovered_tag, clicked_tag;
 public:
  std::string const& get_texture_tag() const; // returns one of its tags
};
class Drawer {
 private:
  std::map<std::string, Texture> textures;
 public:
  void draw(std::string const&, Position) const;
};
void App::draw() {
  drawer.draw(button.get_texture_tag(), position);
}
```

The first approach seems to be representing `Button` as a fully made up object yet aware of the drawing submodule. The second design shakes off such coupling and is (likely) easier to parallelize; however, its `Button` looks like a silly DTO and provides much less convenient interface (though the difference isn't noticeable in the examples provided, the real one is painful).

Which decision is usually preferred and why? Are there any possible problems (or other solutions) I didn't notice?

Comment: If you'd want to reuse one texture for different objects you'd need to keep a lot of copies around in memory with the first approach

Comment: @UnholySheep however, a `shared_ptr` would manage.

Comment: Yes, but then you'd still need an additional system to make sure that you reuse the texture (and don't load it again if it's already loaded) - at which point you don't have that much difference between the first and second system anymore

Comment: @UnholySheep I actually load all textures (needed for the current state) at once so it's not a problem in my case. Your point seems reasonable though it still isn't convincing enough for a choice in my situation. If you have anything more to say, it can fit the format of an answer, I think :)